# How do I find constraints on the Nambu-Goto Action?

Tags: string-theory, constrained-dynamics

Let $X^\mu (t,\sigma ^1,\ldots ,\sigma ^p)$ be a $p$-brane in space-time and let $g$ be the metric on $X^\mu$ induced from the ambient space-time metric.  Then, the Nambu-Goto action on $X^\mu$ is defined to be
$$
S:=-T\int dt\, d\sigma \sqrt{-\det (g)}.
$$
(We use the convention of space-time signature $(-,+,+,+)$.)

Let us try to compute the Hamiltonian for this theory.  The first step is to calculate the conjugate momenta:
$$
P_\mu :=\frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial _tX^\mu)},
$$
where of course $L:=-T\sqrt{-\det (g)}$.  It turns out that you are unable to invert this map to write $\partial _tX^\mu$ as a function of $X^\mu$, $P^\mu$, and $\partial _{\sigma ^i}X^\mu$, which means that the image of the Legendre transformation $(X^\mu ,\partial _{\sigma ^i}X^\mu ,\partial _tX^\mu )\mapsto \left( X^\mu ,\partial _{\sigma ^i}X^\mu ,\frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial _tX^\mu )}\right)$ is not surjective, but instead the image of this map is a proper sub-manifold (of course, in general the image of a manifold under a smooth map will not in general be a manifold, but in our particular case, that should not be a problem) of $T^pT^*M$, and so (locally anyways) will be specified by $N$ constraints $\phi _j(X,\partial _{\sigma ^i}X,P)=0$, where $N$ is the dimension of the kernel of the derivative of the Ledgendre transformation.

In the case of the Nambu-Goto Lagrangian, I have found that $N=1+p$.  I found this by calculating the multiplicity of $0$ as an eigenvalue of $\frac{\partial ^2L}{\partial (\partial _tX^\mu )\partial (\partial _tX^\nu )}$.  The question is:  now that I know how many constraints there should be, how do I systematically find what those constraints actually are?

For what it's worth, I know that one constraint is
$$
P^2+T^2\det (k)=0,
$$
where $k$ (I have suppressed the time-dependence of $k(t)$ in the notation) is the metric on the space-like sub-manifold $X_t^\mu (\sigma ^1,\ldots ,\sigma ^p):=X^\mu (t,\sigma ^1,\ldots ,\sigma ^p)$ induced from the metric $g$ on $X^\mu$, and that the other $p$ constraints are
$$
\partial _{\sigma ^i}X\cdot P=0
$$
for $1\leq i\leq p$.  I even know how to verify that these are in fact constraints.  What I don't know, however, is how to come up with these constraints without simply pulling them out of my ass.

Is there a systematic, yet computationally feasible way of determining what these $1+p$ constraints should be?

Furthermore, I have a hunch that each of these constraints arises from a corresponding re-parameterization invariance, so if that is indeed the case, it would be wonderful if someone could elucidate this connection for me.  (Is there a re-parameterization invaraince-$\Rightarrow$-constraint theorem analogous to Noether's Theorem for symmetries and conserved quantities?)

Comment: Could you explain how did you calculate the multiplicity of 0 as an eigenvalue of that matrix?

Comment: Actually, since it's been a little over two years now since I actually did the computation, I admittedly don't remember exactly what I did, and I can't say for sure unless I just re-do everything.  I can, however, tell you the first thing I would try . . .

Comment: Write out the formula for $\det (g)$ using the co-factor expansion along the first column (or row) to obtain an explicit formula for $L$.  For concrete-ness, take the space-time dimension to be, say, $D=4$.  This way, you will be able to write down an explicit formula for the matrix $\frac{\partial ^2L}{\partial (\partial _tX^\mu )\partial (\partial _tX^\nu )}$ (of course if you want a general proof you will need to do it for arbitrary $D$).  The point of doing this is that now we will have a very explicit $4\times 4$ matrix that you can just plug-in to Mathematica (or some other CAS) . . .

Comment: Then you can just have Mathematica row-reduce this matrix so that you can just read-off the multiplicity of $0$ as an eigen-value.  If you do this for several different values of $p$, you should see a pattern.  This of course gives you the answer.  To prove it, you would have to turn this calculation into a proof; I am quite confident that I never actually bothered to do that.

Comment: Honestly, there is probably a much more clever way to do this, but I personally don't think it is a wise use of time to try to find a better solution to something like this.

Comment: Thanks for your time! I will try to get the cofactor expansión for $det(g)$. Then I am going to use $H_{\mu\nu}b^\mu=0$ to find how many eigenvectors there are. I have done that for $p=0$ and $p=1$ with succes.

Comment: Why can't you just apply the Dirac's method? That is, consider the relations that comes out from the definition of the momenta as constraints and require its constancy in time until there arises no more independent constraints? Sorry if the answer to this is obvius, I independently study constrained dynamics and just arrived at the Nambu-Goto action studying string theory, also by myself, so I'm unaware of possible subtleties.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to find a quasi-systematic way to do this.  The idea that allowed me to do this was inspired by Noether's Theorem.

Re-parameterization invariance is a symmetry of the system, a symmetry much stronger than an ordinary global symmetry.  Similarly, however, a constraint is also a conserved quantity, but it is something much stronger than that.  Knowing that there was some relation between the two, I suspected there might be a way to derive constraints given re-parameterization invariance in a similar way that Noether's Theorem allows you to derive conserved quantities from a known symmetry.  I thus managed to hack together a modification of the'proof' of Noether's Theorem that allowed me to calculate the constraints.  Unfortunately, however, putting the constraints entirely in terms of $X$, $\partial _{\sigma ^i}X$, and $P$ was not completely systematic, but it was still much more straightforward than simply coming up with the constraints out of thin air.  Anyways, here's what I did.  For simplicity, I only addressed the case of the string ($p=1$).

For a mapping of the string $X\mapsto X'$ which depends on a parameter $\varepsilon$, I abbreviate $\frac{d}{d\varepsilon}\big| _{\varepsilon =0}$ by $\delta$.  This notation is common amongst physicists, but they often do mention exaclty what they mean by it.  Under such a transformation of the string alone, I have
\begin{align*}
\delta L & =\frac{\partial L}{\partial X}\cdot \delta X+\frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial _tX)}\cdot \delta (\partial _tX)+\frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial _\sigma X)}\cdot \delta (\partial _\sigma X) \\
& =\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left[ \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial _tX)}\right] \cdot \delta X+\frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial _tX)}\cdot \delta (\partial _tX)+\frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma}\left[ \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial _\sigma X)}\right] \cdot \delta X \\
& +\frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial _\sigma X)}\cdot \delta (\partial _\sigma X) \\
& =\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left[ \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial _tX)}\cdot \delta X\right] +\frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma}\left[ \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial _\sigma X)}\cdot \delta X\right] .
\end{align*}
Note that I have assumed that the derivatives commute with the transformation (i.e. $\delta (\partial _tX)=\partial _t(\delta X)$ and $\delta (\partial _\sigma X)=\partial _\sigma (\delta X)$).  In the case of our re-parametrization invariance, this turns out to be the case, though I did have to check this and I don't see any reason why this should be true in general (though do point it out if you are aware of a reason)).

Assuming that $\delta L$ is of the form $\delta L=\partial _tf+\partial _\sigma g$, we can re-arrange this equation to obtain
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left[ \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial _tX)}\cdot \delta X-f\right]=\frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma}\left[ g-\frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial _\sigma X)}\cdot \delta X\right] .
$$
Thus, under the assumption that the appropriate functions vanish at infinity, the integral over $\sigma$ of the quantity in the time derivative will be conserved.  We suspect this might be a constraint.  This is enough motivation to write down that quantity to see if it is in fact a constraint (note that the above derivation is only supposed to be *motivation to check*, not an actual *proof*).

In the case of time re-parametrization $X(t)\mapsto X(t+\varepsilon \xi )$, $\delta X=\xi \dot{X}$ and $\delta L=\partial _t(\xi L)$ (the first you can see right away, the second I had to actually sit down and calculate).  Thus, we suspect that
$$
\xi \dot{X}\cdot P-\xi L=\text{const}
$$
might be a constraint.  In fact, if you calculate $P$ and plug it in, we indeed see that this expression vanishes identically.  So indeed it is true that
$$
\partial _tX\cdot P=-L.
$$
If you do the same thing with $\sigma$ re-parameterization, you find
$$
\partial _\sigma X\cdot P=0.
$$
Note that in this case $\delta L$ is a $\sigma$ derivative, as opposed to a time derivative as before, and so doesn't show up.  Fantastic!  The only thing that remains to be down is to eliminate the pesky $\dot{X}$.  To do this, we have to actually compute $P$.

It turns out that
$$
P_\mu =\frac{T^2}{L}\left( (\partial _tX\cdot \partial _\sigma X)\partial _\sigma X_\mu-(\partial _\sigma X)^2\partial _tX_\mu \right) .
$$
The idea is that we can use the time re-parameterization constraint to eliminate $\partial _tX$ from the expression for $P$ by contracting $P$ with itself:
$$
P^2=\frac{T^2}{L}\left( (\partial _tX\cdot \partial _\sigma X)\partial _\sigma X\cdot P-(\partial _\sigma X)^2\partial _tX\cdot P\right) =-T^2(\partial _\sigma X)^2.
$$

Et voila!  There be the sought after constraints!

And now I move on with my life . . .